# googlefinance function in google sheets can't get min when N/A value

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to get the min price in a range of date using googlefinance function. However, some of the stocks have a missing #N/A value. Using a simple min function doesn't work.

I tried wrapping a filter function, however, since I am getting the values from a googlefinance function, I am not sure what to put for arguments.

```
=MIN(filter(Index(GOOGLEFINANCE("BAC";"low";"2016-11-2";"2017-11-2";"DAILY");;2));SOMETHING<>0)
```

Edit: Found a pretty ugly solution. It's working, but I'm still open to a better solution.
Here is solution:

```
=MIN(filter(Index(GOOGLEFINANCE("BAC";"low";"2016-11-2";"2017-11-2";"DAILY");;2));Index(GOOGLEFINANCE("BAC";"low";"2016-11-2";"2017-11-2";"DAILY");;2)<>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=query(GOOGLEFINANCE("BAC","low","2016-11-2","2017-11-2","DAILY"),"select min(Col2)")
```

The above should return (currently):

```
min Low
16.28
```

I left the label deliberately in an attempt to reassure that the result was not merely some random number. An edit has been suggested to strip this off, using INDEX, which is fully viable (wrap in `INDEX(....,2,1)`) but my preference in this case for the same result would be to avoid a further function and remove the label within the existing QUERY:

```
=query(GOOGLEFINANCE("BAC","low","2016-11-2","2017-11-2","DAILY"),"select min(Col2) label min(Col2) ''")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't mess around with cell formulas much but this seems to be working for me:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("BAC","low52")
```

the result was 16.35

Comment: Thanks, but I am actually looking at max and min values of the past 1 year, but also last 2 years. This is why I am creating a formula like this.